# What is the difference between glPolygonMode GL_LINE and glDrawElements GL_LINE_LOOP mode?

Tags: c++, opengl

The following code snippets give me exactly the same result:

1. ```
   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
   glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, vbo.rows(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
   ```
2. ```
   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
   glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, vbo.rows(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
   ```
3. ```
   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vbo.rows(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
   ```

So is there a different purpose for each option? (or is `GL_LINE_LOOP` just an override of the polygon mode)?

EDIT: I'm playing around with libigl example project. The following is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) change the rasterization mode, but does not change the primitive. There is still a `GL_TRIANGLES` primitive drawn. `glPolygonMode` has no effect on other primitives than triangles. The `GL_LINE_LOOP` is a different primitive type. Try to draw multiple separated triangles outlines with `GL_LINE_LOOP`.

Comment: How many triangles are you drawing?

Comment: @NicolBolas I was playing around with libigl example project. I'll add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: If you try to draw multiple **separated** triangles (with a gap between the triangles), then you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) change the rasterization mode, but does not change the [primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive). The primitive type stays the same and there are still `GL_TRIANGLES` primitive drawn. `glPolygonMode` has no effect on other primitives than triangles. `GL_LINE_LOOP` is a different primitive type. It connects all the vertices to a single line. If you try to draw multiple separated triangles (with a gap between the triangles), then you'll see the difference. You can draw multiple separate outlines of triangles with `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` and `GL_TRIANGLES` primitives, but you cannot with a `GL_LINE_LOOP` primitive.